# C# Selenium multiple windows

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium

I tried to make a script with selenium, where it would open multiple windows/tabs of IE.
Now, it would be easy, except for the fact, that I don't know how many tabs will be open.

This is what i have right now:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ilosc = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
    Join();
}

private void Join()
{
    for (int i = 0; i >= ilosc; i++)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://google.com");
    }
}
```

And I see a couple of problems here, like the variable name for `IWebDriver`.
I also prefer it multi-threaded, since it won't lag the Form this way.
How can i open multiple windows/tabs using this method?

Comment: you should clarify whether you want a multi-threaded operation here.

Comment: I would prefer it to be a multi-threaded program.

Comment: what you want is one thread per driver per browser.  (windows/tabs can be opened from within one browser too, but those would all be in the same thread.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to pcalkins, i managed to find a way!
I made a new thread and started it when the Join() void was called. This is my final code:

```cs
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ilosc = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
            Join();
        }

        void Child()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://google.com");
        }

        private void Join()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= ilosc; i++)
            {
                Thread thr = new Thread(Child);
                thr.Start();
            }
        }
```

It now works perfectly!

Comment: Just a quick suggestion... rather than making `ilosc` "global" in the class, you should just pass it to `Join()` as a parameter from `button1_Click()`.